# Azure Websites - 404 Error on Correct URL path to svg file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor, svg

To the best of my knowledge I've coded this correctly, but I am still getting a 404 error.

---

I thought it might be something wrong with my webconfig, so I added the following mimeType...

## Initial Attempt

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

, but I still receive this error for all of my .svg files.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

---

## Source

I have the following code in a partial view, this simplistically creates the list without error, yet the file path error still shows.

```
@{
    string[,] fruits = new string[1, 3] { { "Kiwi", "kiwi.svg", "bg-kiwi" } };
    string[,] meats = new string[1, 3] { { "Steak", "steak.svg", "bg-steak" } };
    string[,] candy = new string[1, 3] { { "Candy", "candy.svg", "bg-candy" } };
}



@{
    for (int i = 0; i < fruits.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        <div class="item">
            <img class="@fruits[i, 2]" title="fruits[i, 0]" src="~/Images/@fruits[i,1]" />
        </div>
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < meats.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        <div class="item">
            <img class="@meats[i, 2]" title="@meats[i, 0]" src="~/Images/@meats[i,1]" />
        </div>
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candy.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        <div class="item">
            <img class="@candy[i, 2]" title="@candy[i, 0]" src="~/Images/@candy[i,1]" />
        </div>
    }
}
```

---

## Output

```
<div class="masonry" style="position: relative; height: 204px;">
        <div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <img class="bg-kiwi" title="kiwi" src="/Images/kiwi.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 210px; top: 0px;">
            <img class="bg-steak" title="steak" src="/Images/steak.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 420px; top: 0px;">
            <img class="bg-candy" title="candy" src="/Images/candy.svg">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to resolve the path using mvc means:

```
src="@Url.Content("~/Images/@meats[i,1]")"
```

Also make sure your image requests are handled correctly by routing. For instance, you might want to ignore image requests in routing tables:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to ignore image requests in the routing table.

Just a note the URL.Content should be "@URL.Content("~/Images/" + meats[i,1])"